# Queue consumer clusters with ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

How to configure cluster of Consumers in ActiveMQ?
I created a simple embedded ActiveMQ application with two consumers of one Queue, consumers are working in separate threads. But when I send a message to the Queue, JMS delivers it to first consumer no matter how long it sleeps after receiving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to explain that the first consumer is receiving all the messages. There is a FAQ entry for this type of problem available here:

http://activemq.apache.org/i-do-not-receive-messages-in-my-second-consumer.html

Bruce